# Traversing to next input element - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<label>
  <input id="Email">
  <p>...</p>
</label>
<label>
  <input id="randomID">
</label>
```

When a certain thing happens I want the next input AFTER the input with `id=Email` to gain `focus()`

Here's what I'm trying but it fails, meaning, focus not given:

```
$('#Email').nextAll('input').first().focus();
```

I won't always know the ID of the next input otherwise I know it would be easy

Comment: `$('#Email').parent().next().find('input').focus();`

Comment: What do you mean by a certain thing?

Comment: And going strictly by the code you posted, you don't even need the `.first()` in @ArunPJohny's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `label`s add another branch, causing `nextAll` to not find it. `nextAll()` only looks at sibling elements under the same parent.

try this:

```
$('#Email').closest('label').next().find('input').first().focus();
```

As `focus()` will only target the first element in a set anyway, the `first()` is not required:

```
$('#Email').closest('label').next().find('input').focus();
```